# Android ADB Shell doesn't enable packages

Tags: android, apk, adb, samsung-mobile, android-package-managers

I ask to pm (package manager) to enable some package, but it doesn't enable and shows the message "**new state: disabled**"

> shell@android:/ $ pm enable my.app.com
>
> Package my.app.com new state: disabled

Weird... It seems to be a bug...

> Samsung GT-P3100 with Android 4.0.3

Any Idea how to solve it?

Comment: In my case, "pm enable my.app.com" results in message "Killed". Why?

Comment: Is there any message in logcat pertaining to the error?  try *logcat -c && pm enabled my.app.com && logcat -d*.

Answer (score 3):

You may need to be **root** in order to use the command `pm disable <app_package>` on system apps.

Comment: FWIW, looking at the source to `pm`, it appears that a privilege is needed, and the `adb shell` account may or may not have it, depending on how the OS was configured by the vendor (or whether you've rooted it yourself). I get the "Killed" message when running on an HTC One with 4.4.2. When trying the same thing on my Nexus 7 I get an exception message.